# How to run the source code of “mvn dependency:tree”?

Tags: java, maven

I want to know the details of the `mvn dependency:tree` command.
I got the source code from `https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-tree`,
but I didn't find the main method of the main class.
How should I run this source code?

Below is a screenshot of the source code after I downloaded it

[image]

I create a `Run/Debug Configurations`,as follow
and I debug it,I got a error, as follow

[image]

[image]

Comment: Such questions are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, but [here you go](https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/tree/TreeMojo.java)

Comment: Run it using Maven, no? I don't really undestand "run the source code", but I seem to see what you mean. It's a Maven plugin and it does not have (and cannot have) a dedicated main-method-like entrypoint, thus it only can run using Maven or an environment that mimics Maven heavily/entirely (why not use Maven anyway).

Comment: In each class which is named `*Mojo.java` you will find an `execute(..` method. This is the entrance into a plugin... more documentation about the existing goals: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

Comment: @fluffy yes I could run it using maven. But I want to debug the source code (or I want to find test cases), I want to know how maven realizes this function through step-by-step debugging code

Comment: @khmarbaisek thank you very much. I will learn this function entry right away

Comment: If you want to figure out how the plugin works using a debugger, you need to run `mvn dependency:tree` in a Java debugger, set a breakpoint in the mojo's `execute` method and then start it.  But if you are just trying to figure our why something isn't working as expected, *first* try running the `mvn` command with `--debug`

Comment: @StephenC  Can you be more detailed? I don't know how to do it . This code `@Mojo( name = "tree", requiresDependencyCollection = ResolutionScope.TEST, threadSafe = true )
public class TreeMojo
    extends AbstractMojo`

Comment: Detail of what?  Of how to use a debugger?

Comment: @StephenC Can you turn comments into answers? Show me the process of setting a breakpoint, thank you very much！

Comment: No sorry.  You can look up how to set a breakpoint in your IDE's documentation.  Please don't use StackOverflow as an excuse for not doing your own research.  (Now if you were paying me by the hour to tutor you, maybe I would agree to your request.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will first check out how to make the'mvn dependency:tree' command run in the `debugger`

Comment: Start by getting it to run *without* the debugger.  'Cos I suspect that the cause of command syntax error was that the POM it was using didn't have the dependency tree plugin configured.

Comment: @StephenCS I re-edited the question and provided a screenshot of the problem I encountered